# WPF WebBrowser : get Navigation error

Tags: wpf, browser, http-error

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser control inside.

When I navigate to a website, I would like to know if the page is online or not. I the page is not accessible, I would like to navigate to a local html error page...

How can I do it ?

The first solution I found is to do a WebRequest before navigating, but it require a additional website call... I would like to find an other solution.

I wanted to get the HTTP Status code of the page in the "navigated" event of the WebBrowser, but I found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/856608db-48ba-4492-bff1-3721618ff3ae/webbrowsercontrol-navigated-event?forum=wpf) that it's not possible qith a WebBrowser control because the WebResponse is always null...

Is there an other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a common question, I added a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979898/271588) using the .Net NavigationService. Alternatives are also discussed.